# How to disable a particular button in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm going to disable a particular button from a bunch of buttons as below:

```
<button name="paybtn-1" id="paybtn-1" (click)="myfunc(1)">Pay</button>
<button name="paybtn-2" id="paybtn-2" (click)="myfunc(2)">Pay</button>
<button name="paybtn-3" id="paybtn-3" (click)="myfunc(3)">Pay</button>
```

Say, I want to disable `paybtn-1` when it clicked.

In the `ts` file, I pass the `id` of the button however, I stuck how can disable the particular button:

```
myfunc(id){
//
}
```

Comment: if you are sure how many buttons you need, then you can have an array of boolean in ts and bind it with buttons for disabled property

Comment: <input [attr.disabled]="disabled || null"/> should work where disabled is your variable that holds the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You need to do this in proper way, have an array defined in your TS for each button and bind disalbed property to the button. Change it to false when clicking on the button.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara are these buttons are in any data table?

Comment: @ashishpal No, these are not in data table

Answer (score 2):

To disable a button you can use `[disabled]`, like that:

```
<button [disabled]="booleanCondition" name="paybtn-1" id="paybtn-1" (click)="myfunc(1)">Pay</button>
```

An you have to define the `booleanCondition` var in your `.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

To keep in your style:

Add disabled property to the button

`<button name="paybtn-1" id="paybtn-1" [disabled]='disabled["1"]' (click)="myfunc(1)">Pay</button>`

Add method to apply disabled to this button

```
let disabled = {1:false,2:false,3:false}
myfunc(id){
disabled[id] = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case better way  is to disabled button by [disabled attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp).

Component:

```
 element: HTMLElement;    
disableButton(id) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement;
        this.element.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      }
      enableButton(id) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(protocol) as HTMLElement;
        this.element.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
```

HTML:

```
<button [id]="id" name="paybtn-1"(click)="myfunc(1)">Pay</button>
```

NOTE:

id is a var

This works fine for me.